# unhashable type list error

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Whenever I try this line, it gives me this error message:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

what could be the problem?

```
 cprob={(letters[0],):0,
        (letters[0],letters[1]):0,
        (letters[0],letters[1],letters[2]):0, 
        (letters[0],letters[1],letters[2],letters[3]):0, 
        (letters[0],letters[1],letters[2],letters[3],letters[4]):0,
        (letters[0],letters[1],letters[2],letters[3],letters[4],letters[5]):0,
        (['€'],):0,
        (letters[0],['€']):0,
        (letters[0],letters[1],['€']):0,
        (letters[0],letters[1],letters[2],['€']):0,
        (letters[0],letters[1],letters[2],letters[3],['€']):0,
        (letters[0],letters[1],letters[2],letters[3],letters[4],['€']):0}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant language tag to your question.

Comment: Tag your question with the language you're using. And quote the exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tuple is only hashable if all its components are hashable. As such, you cannot use `(['€'],)` (or the other, longer tuples with `['€']` as an element) as a key. Use a tuple instead:

```
(('€',),): 0,
(letters[0], ('€',)): 0,
# etc
```